# How do i factory reset my raspberry pi 4

Tags: reset

I accidentally deleted my main panel, is there a shortcut I can use to reset everything, I found no solutions to bring it back.

Is there also maybe a way to bring back the main panel? I would like a numbed down version, I just got this thing.

I don't get the fancy keywords, sorry!

It is also asking me for a bigger paragraph, so here is this as well.

Comment: The normal solution is to restore from your backup. It is possible to recover from problems, but without knowing what you did no one can say how, just re-image your SD Card with Raspbian.

Comment: What do you mean by "main panel"? You've got an empty desktop after bootup now, or what exactly happens?

Comment: take the sd card out of the pi 4 - it is now in the state it came from the factory - I think "factory reset" is probably the wrong term for what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

take a look at how to install the operating system:  basically you download the latest version of the operating system, unpack it so you have a "xxxxxx.img" file,and then remove the sd card from the pi and completely overwrite it by putting it in another computer and writing the img file onto it.  A proper factory reset!  This is where you get the official operating system from:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
I believe the directions on how to get the img on an SD card for various scenarios can be found from there.
p